# How to convert U => Seq[T] to Stream[U=>T]

Tags: scala, scala-streams

I'm trying to solve this problem. I want to implement this function in Scala

```
def toSeq[U,T](f: U=>Seq[T]): Stream[U=>T] = ???
```

I guess the solution should make use of Stream, but I don't know how to solve this.

**EDIT**

I will try to describe the use case that lead me to this problem. I am creating a DSL to express extractions of data from different datasources. The DSL allows to define extractions like this (U is the source type and T is the extraction type)

```
type Mapping[-U, T] = U => T    
trait Source[T , U]
case class SingleValueSource[T  U](mappings: Seq[Mapping[U, T]]) extends Source[T, U]
case class OptionalValueSource[T , U](mappings: Seq[Mapping[U, Option[T]]]) extends Source[T, U]
case class SeqValueSource[T , U](mapping: Mapping[U, Seq[T]]) extends Source[T, U]
```

I want to be able to combine all this mappings to build new Source, for example

```
def addMapping(source: Source[U,T], mapping: Mapping[U, T]): Source[U,T]
def addMapping(source: Source[U,T], mapping: Mapping[U, Option[T]]): Source[U,T]
def addMapping(source: Source[U,T], mapping: Mapping[U, Seq[T]]): Source[U,T]
```

The function I am asking came up when I was trying to implement

```
def addMapping(source: SeqValueSource[U,T], mapping: Mapping[U, Option[T]]): Source[U,T]
```

But maybe there's a better way

Comment: This is not possible (the function `U => Seq[T]` can return different length `Seq`s, bu the result of calling `toSeq` returns one fixed-length `Seq`). Did you mean the inverse of this function?

Comment: I agree that the problem is, at best, underspecified. Can you explain how you want this `toSeq` method to actually behave...?

Comment: @Alec I agree that it's impossible with all collections except the lazy ones, but I am not sure when we use a lazy collection like Stream... but you might be right and this is just a problem with no solution

Comment: I have edited the signature of the function to use Stream as the return value

Comment: I think @Seth Tisue has a point - could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: ok, I am going to edit

Comment: I don't think it's generally possible. If you pass an `f` that just returns an empty `Seq`, what should be the output? An empty stream? But you don't know that `f` returns an empty `Seq` until you apply it. You should provide more context on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @Mikel I guess you mixed up the arguments of `Source` in one snippet. Also, I don't get what `addMapping` methods are supposed to do. Can you give some examples for the cases you implemented?

Comment: @Mikel another question: what do all source types have in common? Shouldn't `SeqValueSource` have `mapping: Seq[Mapping[U, Seq[T]]]`? It seems more consistent.

Comment: I want to be able to build a Source adding Mapping to an existing one, the resulting Source will perform the new mapping plus the other mappings